# How to Trigger Event When Serilog Logs File is Written to?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, serilog

I am trying to display the contents of the Serilog "logs.txt" file in my UWP app. I have it successfully displayed, but now I want it to auto refresh as new log events are created.

So far I tried making a ContentsChanged event listener that subscribes to changes in .txt files in the local files drive.

```
private async void CreateFileUpdater()
{
    List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
    fileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
    var options = new Windows.Storage.Search.QueryOptions(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
    var query = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);
            //subscribe on query's ContentsChanged event
    query.ContentsChanged += Query_ContentsChanged;
    var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();
}

private void Query_ContentsChanged(Windows.Storage.Search.IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
{
    ReadFileAsync(); //This updates the bound variable to display in UI
}
```

However, It doesn't seem to trigger properly when new log events are added to the logs file. So I was wondering if Serilog itself has an event I am just not seeing in the documentation or if there is a better way to detect changes in files or when things are added to files. I just want some sort of event to be called so that I can trigger my ReadFilesAsync() function to update the variable that is bound to my UI.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: By my tests, the ContentsChanged event did work for me. When I create a '.txt' file in local folder, this event will be fired. If I write something in this txt file , this event also will be fired. Have you checked if there're new log events are added to this log file?

Comment: Did you test with my code or is there something that is wrong with my code? I tried to put a breakpoint on the event and see when it fires and it doesn't seem consistent with when my logs write to the file. The log events are going through to the file though. Maybe I will investigate further.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT just tested mine again and it fires a couple times on program launch but won't fire after that when log events occur.

Comment: Please try to manually create a txt file in local folder and write something in it to see if this event will be fired.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Okay it fires when I create it and when I edit and save stuff to it. I am not sure why it doesn't fire when the logs add stuff to the files.

Comment: It seems to not fire when a log event is logged to file, but if i open the log file to make sure the logs were working properly it then fires when I open the file.

Comment: So, this issue only occurred when serilog writes log info to the txt file.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT yes, it just doesn't trigger when serilog writes to the file. It triggers when I write to the file manually, or when I open the file after serilog has been writing to it.

Comment: So, you need to report this issue to [serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way I think to do this, is to create your own custom Sink for Serilog. It will catch any log generated, and then you can filter and output these logs anywhere you want. In my case, I output them to my UI.

Create a sinks class:

```
    public class LogsSink : ILogEventSink
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Format of the output log
        /// </summary>
        readonly string Format = "{0} {1} {2}";

        /// <summary>
        /// Emit the provided log event to the sink.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logEvent">The log event to write</param>
        public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
        {
            var t = logEvent.Timestamp;
            LogMsg msg = new LogMsg()
            {
                Text = logEvent.RenderMessage(),
                Lvl = LevelToSeverity(logEvent),
                TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff") + " -" + t.Offset.ToString(@"hh\:mm"),
            };
            if (LogsViewModel.logFile != null)
                LogsViewModel.logFile.AllText.Add(string.Format(Format, msg.TimeStamp, msg.Lvl, msg.Text));
            LogsViewModel.logFile.AppendText();
        }

        static string LevelToSeverity(LogEvent logEvent)
        {
            switch (logEvent.Level)
            {
                case LogEventLevel.Debug:
                    return "[DBG]";
                case LogEventLevel.Error:
                    MainPageViewModel.statusBar.AddError();
                    return "[ERR]";
                case LogEventLevel.Fatal:
                    return "[FTL]";
                case LogEventLevel.Verbose:
                    return "VERBOSE";
                case LogEventLevel.Warning:
                    MainPageViewModel.statusBar.AddWarning();
                    return "WARNING";
                default:
                    return "[INF]";
            }
        }
    }

    struct LogMsg
    {
        public string Lvl;
        public string Text;
        public string TimeStamp;
    }
```

Register your sink when you instantiate the logger

```
public LogsSink sink;
sink = new LogsSink();
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Sink(sink)
                .CreateLogger();
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: BWhelan, a question please, probably you know,
In the Emit, can I access to the file pat and name of the log?
How can I logging into multiple files by any condition?